# UILabel is nil in initWithCoder

Tags: ios, uilabel

I need to set some label fonts and colors in a table view cell.

I am using:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self customize];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and in the customize method I set two labels to have the same font and text color

```
self.label1.textColor = somecolor;
self.label2.textColor = somecolor; // same color
```

The problem is that they end up having very different color (one dark gray the other light gray) I checked the nib and the outlets are set.
By stepping over the code I noticed that the labels are nil at that point. so where are they instantiated ? Why don't they have the same color?

Comment: Did you check with this method ? Is it called or not? put breakpoint and check with this..

Comment: I said it's called... just all the properties (labels) are nil at that point...

Answer (score 6):

in `initWithCoder` the outlets are yet to be initialized.

Use your custom code in the `awakeFromNib` method which is called after all ui elements/outlets has been loaded and set.

Comment: I have that method (customize) called from initWithCoder ,initWithStyle:, and awakeFromNib... it only gets called from initWithCoder ...

Comment: ups.. it does get called from awakeFromNib... and then the labels are initialized... the just don't get the same color event thou I explicitly set them to the same color.

Comment: first just call customize from awakFromNib. Then although you checked, check again the outlets or change the label's text (of the probelmatic label) to make sure it is connected correctly

Comment: it is connected correctly ... If I change the color they both change the color but one has a more grayed out version of the same color... It's like there is some sort of semitransparent view on top of it (there isn't) ... could this be something to do with tintcolor... they have the same tintColor

Comment: check the alpha value of the labels... make sure they are the same. an alpha value < 1 (>0) will make the color change

Comment: they have the same alpha... there is smt wrong for sure.. but i fixed it in the nib... deleted one of the labels and copied the other one .. now it seems to work

Comment: tried the same thing (copy paste) with another set of labels in the same cell...  doesn't work .. great

Comment: I think this has something to do with blended layers... does anyone have any ideea